# actionscript strange getter/setter access

Tags: actionscript-3, interface, getter-setter

Conceiving a library according to the "Factory" design pattern, i need to distinguish the interfaces to consider as "read only" and those that can also have a write right. So, I develop the following schema:

```
public interface IReadOnly {
    function get value (): Number;
}
public interface IReadWrite extends IReadOnly {
    function set value (v:Number): void;
}
internal class ReadWrite implements IReadWrite {
    public function get value (): Number {
        return m_value;
    }
    public function set value (v:Number): void {
        m_value = v;
    }
    protected var m_value:Number;
}
```

So the problem is: I cannot access to the getter on an instance of the class. Flex will refuse to compile the following code:

```
function doSomething (rw:IReadWrite): void {
    var num:Number = rw.value;
}
```

Flex tell me : "1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property value through a reference with static type IReadWrite."
When I replace the setter by a simple function such as `function setValue (v:Number): void;` every thing goes well.
Has somebody already ran into this scenario ? Is it a compiler bug ? Any compiler parameters that can resolve the problem ?
Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you ever managed to solve this, but I found a workaround. You need to cast the object that the getter is being called on to the Interface that actually defines the getter method. So the function call would look like this:

```
    function doSomething (rw:IReadWrite): void {
    var num:Number = IReadOnly(rw).value;
}
```

It looks ugly but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, ugly and not really "user friendly" since my code will be packed into a lib for other devs. But with a clear documentation, that let me having a nice lib design. (i would like to up your answer but i can't since my "reputation" is not yet good enough...)

Answer (score 1):

Your IReadWrite interface is incorrectly extending the ReadWrite class; It needs to extend the IReadOnly interface.

I'm surprised the compiler even lets you declare an interface that extends a class.

Comment: Sorry, on the exemple, i have forgotten the "I" in front of the "ReadOnly" on "IReadWrite" interface declaration. So, my IReadWrite interface really extends the IReadOnly interface. I edit my post to correct this mistake.